# Verify container running state

Tags: bash, docker

I have a `bash` script, which I use to run several `Docker` containers. Initialization time differs on system specifications, so sometimes these cannot be started in specified order. How can I detect with use of `bash`, that a container is running, so following container can be started. Containers requires previously started containers.

Comment: isn't it possible to do so with compose?

Comment: @Auzias : I don't know, but good idea! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend using bash for this. My ideal  choice would be Ansible. But since your requirement is bash, so you'd do something like this (It's not the exact code just an example):

```
CONTAINER=my_container_id_or_name

RUNNING=$(docker inspect --format="{{ .State.Running }}" $CONTAINER)

while [ true ]; do
        if ["$RUNNING" == "true"]; then
                echo "$CONTAINER is running. Now start your other container"
                exit 0
        else
                echo "$CONTAINER is not running. Sleep for 1 second"
                sleep 1
        fi
done
```

Answer (score 1):

you can find all the running containers with `docker ps` and filter them on various criteria with `--filter=`

It is convenient to start a container with a `--name` 
the doc for `docker run`

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/

extract

`--name=""                     Assign a name to the container`

and you can then filter with `docker ps --filter name=`

See the doc for `docker ps`

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/ps/

an example

`docker ps --filter "name=captvty"`

you can also filter with the image, the label, the ancestor, the id...